# Extracting arguments for an exec function

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, exec

I'm trying to figure out a project for school and I'm pretty close. The goal is to emulate using a terminal, essentially inputting a series of commands with pipes and having them execute correctly.

My current code and output is listed below but the main gist is that I have been able to separate commands and arguments thus far, but when attempting to use an strcat on line 83, I feel to get a segmentation fault.

The lines I attempted to add were:

```
    strcat (allargs, print);
}
printf("\n %s -- ALLARGS\n ", allargs);
```

What would be the best way to extract a string of all the arguments? As I'm looking to use either execvp or execlp, would there be a better way to go about this?

Thanks!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <wait.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    // count number of "|" in string
    int count_cmds(char *str)
    {
        int count = 1; // always will be 1 cmd
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '|')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    char *get_token_at(char *command, size_t n, char *delimiter)
    {
        size_t position = 0;
        char *copy = strdup(command);
        char *token = strtok(copy, delimiter);
        char *output = NULL;
        while (token && position < n)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            position++;
        }
        if (token && position == n)
            output = strdup(token);
        free(copy);
        return output;
    }
    
    // trim whitespace
    char *trimwhitespace(char *str)
    {
        char *end;
        while (isspace(*str))
            str++;
        if (*str == 0)
            return str;
        end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
        while (end > str && isspace(*end))
            end--;
        // new end of string
        *(end + 1) = 0;
        return str;
    }
    // count spaces in a string
    int count_spaces(char *str)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    int fd[2];
    int x;
    int execc(char *command, int i)
    {
    
        printf("--- NEW CALL TO EXECC ---------------- COMMAND PASSED: %s \t\t\t\t\t\t ---- NUMBER PASSED: %d\n", command, i);
    
        char *text = trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i - 1, "|")));
        char *textargs = text;
        char *allargs = " ";
        for (int k = 0; k < count_spaces(textargs); k++)
        {
            char *print = trimwhitespace((get_token_at(textargs, k + 1, " ")));
            printf("\n %s -- TEXTARG\n ", print);
        }
        char *cmd_only = get_token_at(text, 0, " ");
        printf("\n %s -- cmd only\n ", cmd_only);
    
        int x = fork();
    
        if (x < 0)
        {
            perror("fork error");
            exit(1);
        }
        // parent
        if (x > 0)
        {
            printf("IN PARTENT -- wait for child\n");
            wait(&x);
            return x;
        }
        // child
        if (x == 0)
        {
            printf("NEW CHILD -- exec or call next \n");
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            }
    
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                char *z1 = trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i - 1, "|")));
                printf(" i=1 ---------------- \n%s\n %s \n %s ", z1, z1, trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i - 1, " "), NULL)));
                // execlp(z1,z1, (trimwhitespace(get_token_at(command, i, " ")), NULL)); // if last command, exec
            }
            else
            {
                execc(command, --i); // if not last command, recurse
                char *z2 = trimwhitespace(get_token_at(command, i - 1, "|"));
                printf("i!=1 --------------------\n%s\n %s \n %s ", z2, z2, trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i - 1, " "), NULL)));
                // execlp(z2,z2, trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i, " "), NULL)));
            }
            // char* z3 = trimwhitespace(get_token_at(command, i-1, "|"));
            // printf("%s\n %s \n %s \n",z3,z3, trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i-1, " "), NULL)));
            // execlp(z3,z3, trimwhitespace((get_token_at(command, i, " "), NULL)));
        }
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        printf(" Enter Command>");
        char cmd[50];
        fgets(cmd, 50, stdin);
        int num_cmds = count_cmds(cmd);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Command count: %d\n", num_cmds);
        execc(cmd, num_cmds);
    
        pipe(fd);
        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        {
            printf("Error pipe\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

> ./current  Enter Command>ls -l | sort -r | grep -h
>
> Command count: 3
> --- NEW CALL TO EXECC ---------------- COMMAND PASSED: ls -l | sort -r | grep -h
> ---- NUMBER PASSED: 3
>
> -h -- TEXTARG
>
> grep -- cmd only  IN PARTENT  NEW CHILD
> --- NEW CALL TO EXECC ---------------- COMMAND PASSED: ls -l | sort -r | grep -h
> ---- NUMBER PASSED: 2
>
> -r -- TEXTARG
>
> sort -- cmd only  IN PARTENT  NEW CHILD
> --- NEW CALL TO EXECC ---------------- COMMAND PASSED: ls -l | sort -r | grep -h
> ---- NUMBER PASSED: 1
>
> -l -- TEXTARG
>
> ls -- cmd only  IN PARTENT  NEW CHILD

Comment: Start with simpler commands (just the command, no argument and no pipes) and use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Write (or draw) pointers and what they point to using pen and paper while debugging. Once you're certain this works perfectly, then add one argument, two arguments, three arguments. Then go back to no arguments, but with a pipe. Add one argument to the first command, a second, a third. Then no arguments on the first, but one on the second, two and three. And lastly both commands with one, two and three args.

Comment: Do not delete the code from your question after you have an answer. Either don't ask the question in the first place or leave it intact.  After you've accepted an answer, the question must be left alone.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's up to the user based on their opinions on whether they leave it up, as it's a school project, it would be detrimental to me to leave the whole code freely available.

Comment: Nope — that is not the case.  If it is likely to be detrimental to you, you should not have asked the question in the first place.  Once you asked the question and accepted an answer, you are not at liberty to discard the work of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should define `allargs` as a char array, not a pointer,

Like this:

```
char allargs[64] = {0};
```